# Google Api PHP Client Syntax Error on PHP 7

Tags: php, wordpress, google-api-php-client

- OS: macOS Big Sur
- PHP version:  7.4.1
- Package name and version:  google/apiclient: ^2.12.3

Whenever I switch the PHP version to 7.4.1 I get this error

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'static' (T_STATIC) in /Users/webtechstreet4/Local Sites/fvtest/app/public/wp-content/plugins/form-vibes-pro/vendor/psr/cache/src/CacheItemInterface.php on line 75`

The library works great on PHP 8 but gives the above error when switching to PHP 7.

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: You have a `vendor` directory so you seem to be using Composer, intentionally or not. If you switch PHP versions, you need to run `composer install` to get the appropriate versions of your libraries. Also, is `form-vibes-pro` part of the Google Api PHP Client?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, i am using Composer.
And `form-vibes-pro` is not a part of the Google API PHP Client, it just a directory name where all the libraries/packages are installed.

Comment: First of all why you want to switch versions for the same project, I recommend to always use the stable version that suits your project requirements

Comment: My guess is that it's a WordPress plugin being developed. It makes sense to test every supported version.

Comment: @sree I am developing a WordPress plugin so i need to test the plugin on different PHP versions as the end users may have different PHP versions.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I sorted it out by changing the system PHP version and running `composer update`.
I thought I needed to change the site PHP version but it was actually the system PHP version.

here is the GitHub issue link: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/2246

Answer (score 0):

it is because, static return type is available only for PHP 8, I have same issue, just for temporary you can change
`.\vendor\psr\cache\src\CacheItemInterface.php`
line number 75 just remove return type static like this
`public function set($value);`